# fresh variables are not shown in found models

Tags: z3, smt, z3py

I am using z3 to write a static checker. I have the following problem:

```
>>> from z3 import *
>>> s = Solver()
>>> s.add(FreshInt() + FreshInt() > 0)
>>> s.check()
sat
>>> s.model()
[]
```

As you can see, fresh variables are not shown in the model. I also cannot get their value:

```
>>> a = FreshInt()
>>> s.add(a > 3)
>>> s.check()
sat
>>> s.model()
[]
>>> s.model()[a]
```

I've looked in the docs but I cannot find a way to change this behaviour. I could generate unique variables myself, but it would be nice if z3 can take care of that for me. Can someone point me in the right direction? Or is it not possible to change this in z3py?

Comment: I think this is due to the `FreshInt`; those can be considered "internal". Using `a = Int('a')`, the example works as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FreshInt`/`FreshReal` etc. are intended for creating internal variables that are not user-visible. You should instead use `Int('name')` and `Real('name')` to create user level variables that will be shown in models.

If you really want to see the value, you can add an `observer` function and use it like this:

```py
from z3 import *

def observeInt(s, a):
    obs = Int('observer')
    s.add(obs == a)
    # might want to check the following really returns sat!
    s.check()
    print s.model()[obs]

s = Solver()
a = FreshInt()
s.add(a + FreshInt() > 0)
s.add(a > 12)
print s.check()
observeInt(s, a)
```

This prints:

```
sat
13
```

This is not cheap obviously (as it involves a call to `check`), but it is safe and so long as it's used in debugging situations to strong-arm z3 as you put it, it should do the trick.

Comment: I understand. So there is no way to tell the solver/model "I know these are not meant to be user visible, but can you show them to me anyway?", even though it is not the intended behavior?

Comment: I'm not following. If you want to see them, why not just use `Int`/`Real`? That's the only difference. (In other words, if you want z3 to show them to you, just use `Int`/`Real`, and you can use Axel's trick if you don't want to create names yourself.)

Comment: Axel's trick does not guarantee the variable is unique. Sure, you can have a counter, but if you have a bug somewhere you might reuse the name accidentally just because the strings match. By using z3's facility it is only possible to reuse a name if there is a bug in z3, or if I pass around the reference to that variable. I would like to use this extra guarantee in my checker.

Comment: I see your point, and added a "strong-arming" z3 trick to my answer. Hope it works for you!

Answer (score 0):

You could circumvent this restriction as follows:

```
freshIntIdx = 0

def myFreshInt():
    global freshIntIdx
    freshIntIdx += 1;
    return Int('fi' + str(freshIntIdx))

a = myFreshInt()
b = myFreshInt()
s = Solver()
s.add(a + b > 5, a > 0, b > 0, a + b < 10)
print(s.check())
m = s.model()
print("a = %s" % m[a])
print("b = %s" % m[b])
```

Comment: That is indeed what I have now for some portion of my code that needs the result of the unique variables. But I'd prefer if I could strong-arm z3 into telling me the values for fresh variables as well.